# Getting Exception in Data Driven Framework Scenario while using Apache POI

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, apache-poi, data-driven-tests

Getting Exception in Data Driven Framework Scenario while using Apache POI

I am getting the exception when I execute a scenario using datadriven framework with Apache POI. I am not sure if its a version issue, can anyone please take a look at the exception below to see what is causing this issue and any resolution. Let me know if need anymore details.

Versions:
Eclipse: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
WebDriver: 3.4.0
POI: 3.17

As a work around I have added dom4j-1.6.jar and xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.3.0.jar, which dint seem to solve the issue.

```
 EXEPTION:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/common/SystemCache
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.init(POIXMLDocument.java:76)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.<init>(POIXMLDocument.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
    at Carpet_Utility.ExcelUtils.setExcelfile(ExcelUtils.java:24)
    at Carpet_Main.Main1.main(Main1.java:19)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.common.SystemCache
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTbud.png)

Comment: can you add xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar dependency as well?

Comment: Not clear why always the mysterious advise about the needed dependencies. [Component Map](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components) clearly tells the needed dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have downloaded the wrong jar `xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.3.0.jar`.

You have to download the `xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar`.

If you are using maven, then add this dependency in the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or if you want to use jar, then download from here : [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0)

The screenshot of the `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.common.SystemCache` class :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i have already mentioned in a comments section that for apache poi functionality you have to add `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar` dependency as well.

1. If you are using maven then you have to add this dependency in pom.xml along with `dom4j-1.6.jar`.
2. If you are using through jar dependency then you have to download this jar and then have to include in your project.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, this time it worked, I dint pay attention that the incorrect jar was downloaded

Comment: @ZeeMo can you accept the answer also up vote as well so that this comment will be useful for someone else.